# Why does Pandas not group weeks starting with the specified day?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to group data by week (Sunday - Saturday) and sum each of the days in that week. For some reason, Pandas doesn't group the way I expect. Here is some sample data starting with Sunday Feb 12 2023, and ending with Saturday Feb 25 2023. I expect to pass in `pd.Grouper(freq='W')` or `pd.Grouper(freq='W-SUN')` but it doesn't use conventional weeks unless I pass in `freq='W-SAT'`.

What's going on?

```
$ python
Python 3.8.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct 12 2021, 21:50:56) 
[Clang 11.1.0 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> S = pd.Series([1,2,3,70,2,3,4,5,6,10,20,4,9,1],
...               pd.DatetimeIndex(['2023-02-%d' % d for d in range(12,26)]))
>>> S
2023-02-12     1
2023-02-13     2
2023-02-14     3
2023-02-15    70
2023-02-16     2
2023-02-17     3
2023-02-18     4
2023-02-19     5
2023-02-20     6
2023-02-21    10
2023-02-22    20
2023-02-23     4
2023-02-24     9
2023-02-25     1
dtype: int64
>>> S.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W-SUN',origin='start_day')).sum()
2023-02-12     1
2023-02-19    89
2023-02-26    50
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: int64
>>> S.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W-SAT',origin='start_day')).sum()
2023-02-18    85
2023-02-25    55
Freq: W-SAT, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, the functionality is working as desired. To perhaps simplify the convention, the argument you pass is the date in which you would expect your week to **end**. Therefore, for a sunday to saturday week, you indeed need `W-SAT`. This is specified [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets). Even though for weeks it doesn't specify the end criteria, for following anchors, it does:

> W-SAT weekly frequency (Saturdays)

> (B)Q(S)-DEC
> quarterly frequency, year ends in December. Same as ‘Q’

> (B)Q(S)-JAN
> quarterly frequency, year ends in January

Using `W-SAT` causes the aggregation to start on a sunday and run until saturday to complete the 7-days.

Comment: Where does it mention the 'end' for grouping weekly? I've looked at that page for a while and couldn't find it for grouping. Maybe the bug here is in the documentation.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the Grouper docs that mentions this. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html

Comment: Did you check the hyperlink I used? Except for the weekly anchoring, all others specify that the month or period being stated is the end one. You should focusing on the anchored offsets within the Grouper function, rather than the function itself (it's also referenced in the link you shared under `freq`)

Comment: "Except for the weekly anchoring, all others specify that the month or period being stated is the end one." -- that is an assumption that you are making in documentation about anchored offsets. It is a reasonable assumption, but it is still an assumption that should be clarified that anchoring specifies an *interval* defined by an *end date*.